# phpmailer: Sending email with attachment and setting the name of the file

Tags: php, phpmailer, email-attachments

I wrote a script that generates a pdf file and sends it by email with phpmailer.
In the email I change the name of the pdf file to a more descriptive name.

```
$mail->addAttachment('assets/old_filename.pdf','new_name.pdf');
```

In some email clients like Gmail the file is readable but when you download it it is saved without the extenstion.
If I don't set the name of the attachment it is saved with the extension (pdf).
I tried setting a mime type and also sending it with codeigniter. It doesn't help.

Comment: It seems to me that you are using phpmailer. You can try following this example https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps

Answer (score 0):

PHPMailer will automatically set the right MIME type for `.pdf` attachments, so it's not that. I suggest inspecting the source of the received message, and you should be able to see the filename in the attachment part headers. If it's correct there, but is removed when you save, that's a gmail problem, nothing to do with your message.